# need to pass index of form Array and value of same from in custom validation to validate slab amount reactive form

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm validation slab amount so i have using FormArray but while creating custom validation i am unable to pass FormGroup index of that form control

```
export function maximumAmountValidation(formArray: FormArray, index: number): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
  return null;
}
```